# Build boost libraries for sh4 arhitecture

Tags: c++, boost, embedded-linux

I have the following problem. I need to buld some boost libraries for sh4 platform. I'm trying to use boost.build tool for this aim. I have made for desktop and all are okey - it seems I'm doing all correctly for x86. But for sh4 does not work. I heard that this may not be trivial. Can you give advice?
I have corresponding toolchain and etc...

Comment: Can you please show the error message?

Comment: @Philipp, I'm doing the following steps.
1. edit user-config.jam adding compiler description:
using gcc : 4.8.2 : /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin ;
2. cd ~/boost/distr/boost_1_64_0/tools/build
3. ./bootstrap.sh
4. ./b2 install --prefix=~/boost/install/x32
5. cd ~/boost/distr/boost_1_64_0
6. export PATH=$PATH:~/boost/install/x32/bin
7. b2 --build-dir=~/boost/result/x64 toolset=gcc --stagedir=~/boost/result/x64/libs
After this I receive build error:
sh: 1: /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin: Permission denied
If I run last commond with sudo then:
sudo: b2: command not found

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have found where was my mistake. In user-config.jam file I made mistake when defined rule for toolchain:
**using gcc : 4.8.2 : /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin** - that is path to the toolchain directory. Instead of I should write full path to the executable file:
should be **using gcc : 4.8.2 : /opt/STM/STLinux-2.3/devkit/sh4/bin/sh4-linux-g++**